# Hide Audio device using codeless kext

Tags: macos, usb, kernel, core-audio, iokit

I am developing a audio driver to do some custom audio processing using audio reflector driver sample code from Apple. Output from audio reflector driver is passed to real USB audio hardware device using core audio application. Now I want to hide USB audio hardware device from the system preferences so that user is not able to select the USB audio hardware output device as the default output device. Using the "SampleUSBAudioOverrideDriver" codeless kext I am able to change the name of output interface but not hide it. Any idea on how I will be able to hide  USB audio hardware output device.

Thanks in advance.

Vin Pai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lof of R&D on this topic, I found that codeless kext provided in the sample code, SampleUSBAudioOverrideDriver doesn't use the property set to hide the device interface.

Comment: Could share to us which property of  “use the property set to hide the device interface”  ?