# Where to start in writing an app to modify the output of all sounds on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, avaudioplayer, kernel-extension

I am interested in writing a small utility to modify all audio output on OS X.  I essentially want to apply a certain effect to the sound systemwide and/or via individual applications (similar to how Prosoft Hear operates).

Where would I start digging in order to accomplish this?  Is this done through CoreAudio or are there other more direct option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X virtual audio driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443621/mac-os-x-virtual-audio-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Audio plugins can achieve all sorts of things, those are probably your best bet. I notice you used the kext tag - it's of course possible to do this in the kernel, but that seems overkill.

Comment: Well in one particular case I want to modify all output across the system to change the tonal frequency of the output.  It *seems* that CoreAudio can do this, but I thought that perhaps writing a kernel extension might be necessary.